# Difference between video players in browser and file explorer in Lineage OS

Tags: android, android-videoview, android-9.0-pie, android-video-player, lineageos

I'm trying to play a video file locally but it skips the first 30 seconds and in other cases sometimes gets stuck before playing fluidly.

This happens only when playing from the file explorer. The same file played from URL in the Lineage default browser is fluid and perfectly fine.

I noticed that the issue does not seem to arise for videos with a smaller bitrate.

Example: http://wdrmedien-a.akamaihd.net/medp/ondemand/de/fsk0/213/2136326/2136326_26546252.mp4

OS: Lineage OS 16.0
Device: Fire HD 8

Answer (score 0):

Browsers usually use hardware decoding for video playback. File explorers usually don't focus on this. It's just an convenience to allow video playback in file explorers.

You can use something like VLC player for a better video playback experience.